# Unable to create Maven project, with apache-maven-3.3.3 and JDK1.8.0_66

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-3, maven-plugin

Unable to create Maven project, getting error as :
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

JDK1.8.0_66
apache-maven-3.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Maven cannot download `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6`.

This means you most certainly have a firewall or proxy issue.

Talk to your network administrator to find out what you need to do.